# Convert birthday date with years of last century

Tags: php

I need to store a date that comes from a `CSV` file as `28-Dec-55`  into `MySQL` as `1955-12-28 00:00:00`

If I try `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("28-Dec-55"))` it returns `2055-12-28 00:00:00` therefore I then go on and do `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("28-Dec-55 -100 years"))` and that gives me the expected date of `1955-12-28 00:00:00`

`strtotime("28-Dec-55 -100 years")` does the job, but somehow It feel weird having to rest 100 years to get the right date.

Is there other way to get what I want? (of course there are other ways! but I mean in a simplistic way, maybe I am missing a function that would automatically know that I meant 1955?)

Comment: You cold explode your date string from your csv file and make an addition to the year, than implode back, but this method isn't faster than yours. Isn't faster in terms of line of code written to do your job

Comment: PHP has to make a choice when interpreting a 2-digit year, so it chooses the current century, and anything else would be highly unusual.... you specifically have to tell it otherwise by including a century in the year, or by adjusting after doing the conversion. If it automatically know what century you meant other than the current century, then it would need to be telepathic: it can't know that the date is a birthdate, and not the date for my next appointment at the morticians, that requires human knowedge